# How to get the length of an array when using API( https)?

Tags: angular, api

```
getDepartments(): void {
    this.departmentService.getDepartments().
   subscribe(departments => this.departments = departments);
    //   subscribe(data => this.departments = data);
  }
  getNumDep():void{
    this.depNumber = this.departments.length;
```

Currently I have this and I need to change the `getNumDep` method to get the data from my database. Right now it doesn't count the length of the array and I get this exception:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   at DashboardComponent.push../src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts.DashboardComponent.getNumDep (dashboard.component.ts:59)

Comment: you can assinged length in your subscrirbe. `subscribe(data => {this.departements = data; this.depNumber = this.departments.length)`. Indeed, `getNumDep()` is a getter and return the value

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: console.log data in subscribe and check if it is the array that you want. such kind of errors are pretty common , you must be doing some silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

departmentService.getDepartments() is asynchronous, so if you call getNumDep() before it has returned a value, you will get that error. Generally it's a bad idea to have methods like getNumDep() that will throw an exception if called to early. Instead I suggest assigning length to a variable inside the subscription like @ghuntheur also suggested:

```js
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';  // If you're using rxjs6


getDepartments(): void {
    this.departmentService.getDepartments().
    subscribe(departments => {
        if (departments) {
            this.departments = departments;
            this.depNumber = departments.length;
            this.depNumNotEindhoven = departments.filter(dep => dep.location !== 'Eindhoven').length;
        }
        else {
            Observable.throw("Error: Service didn't return an object")  // If you're using rxjs <6
            throwError("Error: Service didn't return an object");  // If you're using rxjs6
        }
    });
}
```

Make this change, and remove getNumDep() completely. Then when you need to get the length, you can access it from the this.depNumber variable.

EDIT: As a sidenote, the convention is that get...() methods should return the current value. Your getNumDep() does the opposite, by setting the value. To avoid confusion, I suggest you change the name of the method to setNumDep() if you decide to keep it.

Comment: I assume that the logic for this method will be the same?
  getDepNotEindhoven(other:number):void{
    this.departments.forEach(function(department){
      if(department.location != 'Eindhoven'){other += 1;}

    });

I need to change the ForEach

Comment: Thanks I a lot. I have struggled with this for a quite some time. Really appreciated.

Comment: happy I could help :)